# Poner un background-image en angular

Tags: html, css, angular

Quiero una imagen de fondo en el body del index.html (sera el fondo de pantalla de todas las secciones del sitio) pero no se muestra nunca. No entiendo si debo asignar la imagen al body mismo o tengo que hacerlo en el componente app-root

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MiObservador</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
body{
  background-image: url("/src/assets/images/25101.jpg");
}
```

El app.component.css y el app.component.html están vacíos.

Answer (score 1):

Era un error de sintaxis `background-image: url("/assets/images/25101.jpg");`
Al parecer debo quitarle el "/" del principio, tiene que ver con la etiqueta `<base>` del index.html por lo poco que pude llegar a averiguar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes asignarle la propiedad background con la directiva ngStyle que es la manera que usa Angular para modificar los estilos de los elementos, seria algo asi:

```
<div class="image" style="height: 100vh;width:100vw;" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(/src/assets/images/25101.jpg)'}"></div>
```

Comment: Supongo que ese ejemplo es para el body no? Por que no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

En la carpeta assets agregar una carpeta images que contenga a tu imagen
El camino sera **../assets/images/descarga.jpg**

```
// en tu app.component.scss
#sect1 {  
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image:  url("../assets/images/descarga.jpg");  
 
}
//en tu app.component.html
<div id="sect1"class="container">

</div
```